# Can I integrate Google Analytics with my blog, hosted at wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, google-analytics

I have a blog hosted at wordpress.com. How do I integrate it with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

GA requires javascript, and wordpress.com doesn't allow it.

Comment: In addition probably: I assume that wordpress.com want's to feature their own stats instead of the solution of someone else. So as long it's not offered by staff, it's not available.

Comment: That's almost a good enough reason to switch to a self-hosted installation.

Comment: flexibility, that's the key.

Comment: Ripper - for some, it is.